# aws cli query multiple attributes when these attributes are on the same level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-security-group, jmespath

I am using the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185844/how-do-i-determine-what-a-given-aws-security-group-is-associated-with?rq=1) to find information about instances associated with a particular Security Group

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=group-id,Values=sg-123456 --output json
```

this returns (partial output)

```
{
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "Attachment": {
                "AttachTime": "2019-10-09T07:15:44+00:00",
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-01234567",
                "InstanceId": "i-12345678",
                "InstanceOwnerId": "123456789",
                "Status": "attached"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1c",
            "Description": "Primary network interface",
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "sg-number1",
                    "GroupId": "sg-123456"
                },
                {
                    "GroupName": "sg-number_2",
                    "GroupId": "sg-654321"
                }
            ],
```

If I only want to get the instance IDs then I can use a  --query and go down the tree

```
--query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].Attachment.InstanceId'
```

I can do something similar to get all the SG's as well

```
--query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].Groups[*].GroupId'
```

My question is how can I get the InstanceID and the Group.GroupName in one query ?

Or better how do I query multiple attributes when these attributes are on the same level ?

The following did not work:

```
--query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].Attachment.InstanceId','NetworkInterfaces[*].Groups[*].GroupName'
```

Comment: I admit I am probably not using the correct json/JMESPath terminology and the question and title could be edited for better clarity.  I just don't know how to phrase it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can, you will have to use what JMESPath is describing in the examples as [filters and multiselect hashes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-hashes).

With this, you can recreate an object with queries going down the tree.

In your case, with the query:

```
NetworkInterfaces[*].{ 
  InstanceId: Attachment.InstanceId, 
  GroupNames: Groups[*].GroupName 
}
```

and the JSON data:

```json
{
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "Attachment": {
                "AttachTime": "2019-10-09T07:15:44+00:00",
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-01234567",
                "InstanceId": "i-12345678",
                "InstanceOwnerId": "123456789",
                "Status": "attached"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1c",
            "Description": "Primary network interface",
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "sg-number1",
                    "GroupId": "sg-123456"
                },
                {
                    "GroupName": "sg-number_2",
                    "GroupId": "sg-654321"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It gives:

```json
[
  {
    "InstanceId": "i-12345678",
    "GroupNames": [
      "sg-number1",
      "sg-number_2"
    ]
  }
]
```

---

So your commands ends up being:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces \
  --filters Name=group-id,Values=sg-123456 \
  --output json \
  --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].{ 
    InstanceId: Attachment.InstanceId, 
    GroupNames: Groups[*].GroupName 
  }'
```

Comment: Exactly ! Works as advertised.